# How to update /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 on CentOS 5?

Tags: linux, glibc

I was trying to run Sublime Text 2 on CentOS 5. Sublime requires GLIBCXX_3.4.11 and GLIBC_2.11 but the system has GLIBCXX up to 3.4.8 and GLIBC up to 2.5. How can I update glibc and glibcxx without modifying the kernel or updating to CentOS 6?

Answer (score 0):

hmm, I'd download sources of requested library, compile them myself and install (`make install`) in dir where they won't mix with older version (e.g. `/usr/local`). This should work, but can be quite demanding if you never ever make some compilation under linux ...

Comment: I downloaded a later version of libc and tried to configure it. Seems many critical programs such as as, ld and gcc are too old to pass configure. It looks like a lot of work to do to fix them one by one. Is it possible to install the base lib in an isolated environment?

Comment: once i was through similar situation as well, unfortunately I didn't find any normal solution and have to compile everything - yes, it is demanding and in fact, you gonna end up with CentOS 5 but all the system inside would be compiled libraries equivalent to ones from CentOS 6...